# How do I center an image with no stretching on my Android XML layout Splash screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here's my code. It's stretching my image to the width of the screen. I just want it centered with no stretching. What am I getting wrong here?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"         
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_screenhdpi" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a scaleType
`android:scaleType="center"`

Answer (score 2):

i don't understand very good your question, i hope be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_screenhdpi"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the attribute [`scale`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for `ImageView`s. Use center just to center the image in the image default size, and `match_parent` as the size for width and height.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```